# Does a C# event have to have an object type as its first parameter?

Tags: c#

I have a `TCPClient` class. It has several `ClientEvent`s. Originally it followed the standard pattern

`public delegate void ClientEvent(object sender, ClientEventArgs e);`

Only `TCPCLient` uses this event. But I am pretty determined to keep things as standard as possible (all event based things I've seen use `object sender`). However what I don't see the point of, is having to cast `sender` to `TCPClient` every time.

```
 private static void Client_OnReconnect(object sender, ClientEventArgs e) {
            TCPClient client = (TCPClient)sender; 
        }
```

Is there any reason I shouldn't just use

`public delegate void ClientEvent(TCPClient client, ClientEventArgs e);`

as my event?

Comment: Technically, you can specify any parameters (or none) for en event. The `Object_OnEvent(Object, EventArgs)` pattern is just a convention. But it is a very widely used convention, so you might confuse people if you do it differently.

Comment: If you pass the invoker as an `object`, is there anything you can do with it without casting it?

Comment: Yes, there is.  You can do this: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert( invoker == MyVeryOwnClient.Instance );`

Comment: @user2410532: You can do lots of things to objects without casting them. You can interrogate their types. You can put them in a collection of objects. You can turn them into strings. You can compare them for referential or value identity to other objects.

Answer (score 9):

> I am pretty determined to keep things as standard as possible

Good. You are not doing so though. The standard guidelines can be found here:

[MSDN - Event Design for .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011(v=vs.110).aspx)

You have violated the guideline

> use `System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>` instead of manually creating new delegates to be used as event handlers.

Of course guidelines are *guidelines*, not *rules*. The guidelines go on to note that if you for some reason decide to violate this guideline...

> use object as the type of the first parameter of the event handler, and call it sender.

Your question is:

> Is there any reason I shouldn't just use `delegate void ClientEvent(TCPClient client, ClientEventArgs e)` as my event?

That is, if it is the case that the sender will always be a `TCPClient`, why not encode that in the type system?

Well, that violates the design guidelines, but of course that is mere question-begging. Why have this guideline?  The reasoning is because your assertion that the sender of this event will always and forever be `TCPClient` is one that historically has often turned out to be violated. You think that yeah, I'm only ever going to want to handle click events on buttons, so the sender can be `Button`, and then next sprint some UX designer wants to change fully half of the buttons into clickable monkeys, and now the click event needs to apply to both buttons and monkeys, and blah blah blah, you see how this goes.

Again: guidelines are guidelines, not rules. If you have confidence that encoding this restriction into the type system is higher value than the risk of having some designer say "hey, can you change half the clients into TCPMonkey, how hard can it be?" then by all means go for it.

Comment: I have been reading Writing High-Performance .NET Code by Ben Watson and he makes it clear that casting is expensive. While an individual client, in my case, may not fire off that many events, the server that manages them will have many, many clients, and therefore, many client events. To cast these each time sounds problematic. My original method was to simply pass the client into the event args class. I guess I should go back to that method.

Answer (score 6):

The `sender` parameter is so that the callback can recognize the object that's invoking it.  In some situations, that's useful to know.  If you don't need that, though, then you don't need it, and there's no technical, language-level or framework-level reason why you necessarily have to use it.

Comment: Thanks. My secondary question which I forgot to ask is, do classes ever share events? What other class would ever want to fire off a TCPClient event?

Comment: @user2410532: If you have a second question, your best bet is to post a second question.